# gcc extension __attribute__ meanings

Tags: gcc

when I look some code, I find the following snap.

```
void ph_library_init_register(struct ph_library_init_entry *ent);
#define PH_LIBRARY_INIT_PRI(initfn, finifn, pri) \
  static __attribute__((constructor)) \
  void ph_defs_gen_symbol(ph__lib__init__)(void) { \
    static struct ph_library_init_entry ent = { \
      __FILE__, __LINE__, pri, initfn, finifn, 0 \
  }; \
  ph_library_init_register(&ent); \
}
```

my question is:
1. what is **stribute** means?
2. when does the code run?

Answer (score 0):

`__attribute__` in GCC is similar to what other compilers have in the form `__declspec`, although maybe a bit more elaborate (also, GCC supports `__declspec` for compatibility).

Attributes can apply to functions, variables, and types. They can alter the way a thing "behaves" or "looks like" (such as e.g. alignment, visibility, etc.).

In your particular case, `__attribute__((constructor))` means that the function is to be called automatically before `main` executes. It is not specified when exactly this happens, but you can assign a priority with the attribute to gain some control about the relative order of constructors.

Complete documentation of this feature at: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html.

(It should be noted that this is a macro definition, so the code *doesn't actually* run unless you expand the `PH_LIBRARY_INIT_PRI` macro in some other place, too.)